# In how many ways can r elements be chosen from [1..n] with repetition, such that adjacent elements are one-step removed?

Tags: combinatorics

In case any of you is bored on this Wednesday...

For example, choose 4 from [1,2,3]:

1232
3212
1212
...

By "one-step removed," I mean if the element is `x`, then the adjacent element is greater than zero and less than or equal to `n`, and is either `x + 1` or `x - 1`

I'm totally clueless about how to solve this.

Comment: I think this asks for counting $r-1$ step walks, with steps $\pm1$, on a chain of $n$ vertices.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen thank you for your comment. Do you think a formula can be devised based on `n` and `r`?

Comment: Counting walks on bounded regions is somewhat tricky (in any case harder than many combination-type problems). The number of walks on a half-line starting at the end point is still given by a binomial coefficient, but the argument showing that is nontrivial. Here you are not fixing the starting point, and also imposing an upper bound as well, so that looks even more difficult. Try to get some numeric evidence for small values of $n$ and $r$ first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your asking for the number of walks of length $k$ in the directed graph

[image]

in the case $n=5$ (and similarly for other $n$).  The adjacency matrix has the form $$A=\begin{array}{|ccccc|} \hline 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline \end{array}$$ so the number of walks of length $k$ is the sum of the entries of $A^k$.

[Joseph Myers](http://www.polyomino.org.uk/) has an article which gives a formula for computing this sum of entries:

> J. Myers (2008), [BMO 2008–2009 Round 1 Problem 1—Generalisation](http://www.polyomino.org.uk/publications/2008/bmo1-2009-q1.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me/us in that direction. I think I'm starting to visualize it although the math is advanced for me. Do you think there may be a way to extrude the number of only those combinations with consecutive adjacent digits that include all digits (e.g., m=4,n=3 would mean 0121,2101.. but not 1212, etc.)?

Comment: Actually, in regards to the comment above, referring to the formulas in the article, I thought something along the lines of subtracting `m(n,r-1)` from `m(n,r)`, (or do I mean subtracting `m(n-1,r)` from `m(n,r)`).

Answer (score 0):

For the first element, you have $n$ possibilities, for all ather elements, you have $n-1$ possibilities (since the predecessor is forbidden). So the answer is
$$
n (n-1)^{r-1}.
$$

Comment: It's that simple? Thank you for helping me understand more.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct, but it depends on the exact problem - I think having chosen an element, the next element must be an adjacent one, so you have at most 2 choices (and only 1 if the predecessor is one of the endpoints). In all the examples this is the case, and it's what I think "one-step removed" means.

Comment: This works only if the first and last elements are considered to be "one-step removed".

Comment: @groovy: Please read the comments of Matt and Henning and then specify in your question what you mean by "one-step removed".

Comment: @MattPressland thank you for your comment, please see updated clarification.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thank you for your comment, please see updated clarification.

Comment: I think this answer cannot be construed to be correct, even for the original question. The title asks for one-step-removed elements, and I just cannot see how one would interpret that as _forbidding_ to choose the (cyclic) predecessor, especially since predecessors _are_ chosen in each of the examples.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen My interpretation of "one-step removed" was that each chosen symbol is removed from the candidate list for the next single step. ($a_{n+1} \neq a_n$). This is true for all given examples.

Comment: @azimut: OK, I see your point. But it does not go very well with "adjacent elements are one-step removed".